# Is there any logical reasons behind not allowing Vmax to a USB-PD device without communication?

Tags: usb-pd

AFAIK, when the power cable is connected, Usb-pd devices start with 5V and then set the power source to another higher voltage that the device can handle via proper USB communication.

For example, our device can handle 9V. Why can't we simply apply 9V directly to the input? Isn't that simpler in terms of circuit design? Why can't I directly apply 9V with a step-down converter if I know my device can handle 9V?

Comment: It's a USB connector, anyone can plug a device in that would be destroyed by more than 5V

Comment: That still doesn't explain why the device gets broken when we directly apply more than 5V that can obviously handle more than 5V.

Comment: No, it can handle 9V after the proper communication.

Comment: You have to account for all the old devices that were designed when USB was 5V only.  Or the new ones that don't have a front-end converter.

Comment: By OP's logic, every USB-C charger should output 20V by default. Survival of the fittest.

Comment: By my logic, every USB-C device should handle its Vmax when it is applied without any communication.

Answer (score 8):

*Your* device can handle 9V. Some *other* devices can't, and would be destroyed. How does the host know whether the device that was plugged in is one that can handle a higher voltage? By talking to it. But to be sure that the device is available for communication, it needs to supply some power, so it does so at 5V. *5V is the only voltage that everyone has to accept*.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the logical reason is to not give 9V to a device that damages with 9V. Your voltage source has no knowledge where it is plugged in, until they communicate and determine they can use higher voltage than 5V.

And that is why there are standard that define how things are supposed to work, and good standards guarantee interoperability of devices without damage.

Not all devices can handle anything else than 5V. And, not all devices support USB-PD either for any purpose.

That's because Type-C connector is the only connector supporting PD, but it is also backwards compatible with older Type-A connectors which use 5V only.

Therefore, before anything is communicated, everything needs to be backwards compatible and provide only 5V.

And USB Type-C sockets are not even allowed to supply power at all, because you can plug a cable between any two devices, so a socket has to recognize that something requiring power is plugged in before 5V is enabled on a socket.

Only a Type-A plug to Type-C plug adapter cable is allowed to forcibly output 5V, because there is no way to handle it otherwise with a passive adapter cable. And that's why sockets are required to handle 5V without damage even without asking for power. And that also defines that your Type-C plug to Type-A socket adapter needs to provide 5V only, as that is what Type-A devices need.

(Note that I said that only 5V is allowed for Type-A compqtibility. Mobile phone charging over Type-A can use custom protocols to indicate support for providing more than 5V, but your average USB device like a memory stick or mouse would not use those protocols as they just want 5V and data).

Answer (score 0):

> "Why can't I directly apply 9V with a step-down converter if I know my
> device can handle 9V?"

Sure you can. But an arbitrary power provider is not "you", and does not know anything about your device unless there is a communication. So, which voltage a variable power provider should supply to your device? 9V? 15V? 20V? 48V? The logical reason to have a communication seems pretty obvious.

Comment: Okay, then can I apply the voltage that I measure by stripping the USB cable, directly without letting the device establish a communication? I'm told that the device will not handle - eg. 9V - if we apply it directly and burn instantly, even though it perfectly handles 9V after "the proper communication" with the power source.

Comment: @ceremcem, Why do you ask? It is your device, no? However, if the device uses a full-scale PD controller to manage CC communication, it may not turn on the 9-V power path without following the standard sequence, +5V first locally, -> PD communication -> PD contract -> turning on the 9-V power path. But you should know better how your particular device functions, it is your device, right?